# Why is Unity3D on OSX ignoring my XBox 360 controller?

Tags: unity, macos, xbox-controller

I'm using [a fork of the Tattie Bogle driver](https://github.com/d235j/360Controller) that has a signed kext. The System Settings panel shows all inputs correctly.

One axis is configured in Unity3D 5 like this:

[image: Input Manager axis setup]

Still, I don't see any input when the game is running. I also cannot configure Positive/Negative Buttons for any input in the Input Manager panel - clicking the input line edit and entering a keyboard key works fine, but pressing a controller button does nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've found that I need to restart Unity with the controller plugged in for it to be detected. OSX 10.11.3, Unity 5.3.4f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Tattie Bogle Drivers, you also need to use [Unity-XboxCtrlrInput for Unity](https://github.com/JISyed/Unity-XboxCtrlrInput) if you want to use your Xbox Controller on Unity.
It is working for both Unity 4 and Unity 5. 
They have a working example project that you can download from the project page if you want to test your Xbox Controller with a working project.

Comment: This seems to be a different question, not an answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the solution more clearly.

Comment: Interesting I didn't read about this anywhere. Demo project works fine, integration into mine seems to need some work. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research it appears your biggest issue, assuming you have just plugged in and hoped for the best, is that (naturally) mac does not have the drivers to understand an Xbox controller.

A good rule of thumb: If you plug anything Microsoft into anything Apple and just hope for the best, your going to have a bad time. They just don't like talking to each other.
These two sites gave me a bit of insight into connecting various original and third-party controllers. I assume if you follow the driver installation you have a good chance of that fixing everything, just remember that the driver is what the computer uses to understand the device. It is possible that a different driver will interpret the controller a little differently - this may go as far as swapping buttons on the player.

That said, the driver refereed to at jacobtomlinson.com (provided by tattiebogle.net) has come up in a few times in the past, so I would assume that is the general driver players would be using.

http://www.jacobtomlinson.co.uk/2014/10/17/use-xbox-360-pad-with-yosemite/

http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-an-Xbox-360-Controller-on-OS-X-wired-wirele/step2/Wired-third-party-360-controller/

---

Also keep in mind that the drivers impact the identification of the buttons themselves, so you can not use native windows reference to the controller and expect the buttons to remain the same. This last link shows the button references on a Windows system, and the reference system used by the tattieboggle driver.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller

Comment: As I stated in the question, I am in fact using a signed version of the Tattie Bogle driver and the System Settings panel for XBox controllers shows all inputs just fine. Even vibration works. I just cannot seem to make Unity accept input from it.